# Comparing networks using graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, algebraic-graph-theory, network, network-flow

I'm new to graph theory so forgive if I use unconventional terminology. Please ask if there's any confusion regarding the statements I make.

I have a bunch of undirected, unweighted, simple graphs representing communication networks with varying number of edges and vertices. Assume the graph is connected. I need to compare these networks to choose the "best" out of them. Here's how I define the "best";

1. No. of edges and vertices; The more the better
2. Path length from any vertex to another; the shorter the better
3. Likelihood of a [bottleneck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheeger_constant_(graph_theory)); the lesser the better

I might be missing some other aspects which might be relevant for a communication network.

Some concepts that I've read about and not so clear on are;

1. The [Laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) of a graph; Eigenvalues of which are related to the connectivity of the graph ([Algebraic Connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_connectivity),Spectral Gap?)
2. [Conductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductance_(graph)) or [Cheeger constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheeger_constant_(graph_theory)) of the graph
3. Various [centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality) measures

Ideally I would want a measure which is easy to compute for large graphs. Even if its not I would like to know more about them.

So far I've looked into various centrality measures. I'm using Mathematica for analysis and it has an inbuilt library of various centrality measures ([example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EigenvectorCentrality.html)). I constructed a vector from each graph using a particular centrality measure (for example, say the [Eigenvector centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Eigenvector_centrality)), the vector would consist of the centrality measures of the vertices in the graph. I found out that the vectors [majorizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) each other in the direction of decreasing number of vertices. I dont know for sure if this relevant to the question or not.

Comment: You are asking many questions at once here. In particular if you need to understand some particular concepts, please ask separate question about them elaborating what you understood so far and where you have troubles. Something similar applies to your criteria of network quality. While there are single measures addressing your individual criteria, you have to decide how to best combine them for your application. For example, do you rather want to avoid exceptionally bad performances in one aspect or can those be outbalanced by a good performance in another aspect?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4505828/14578, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51760/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: You might be interested in the [diameter](http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/cs267/lecture4.pdf) of a graph, i.e the maximum of the shortest path lengths over all pairs of vertices.  That said, I'm voting to close because the Question doesn't seem precisely formulated enough to allow a definitive answer based on mathematical reasoning or experience.